# Higher secondary school trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Again I have the solution of the problem. However, after seeing the solution, I don't quite understand how is one supposed to know how to approach this problem. My request is tell me how to approach such problems.

And Don't just solve the problem, but also tell me from where do you come to know which approach would work. (Tell me from where do you come to know which trick or approach to be used to solution this problem.) And if possible please give both full subjective solution and short cut method

Thanks in advance.

Here is the answer of this problem [image]

Answer (score 1):

There are trig functions in $x$ and in $2x.$ So we should try using some basic trig identities involving multiples of $x.$ In particular (here) $\tan 2x=2\tan x/(1-\tan^2 x)$ whenever $\tan^2 x\ne 1.$

Isolate the functions of $x$ only and see whether we can simplify and  put them in terms of functions of $2x$.( Here, this works. If this doesn't seem to help in a problem, try the reverse : Express the functions of $2x$ in terms of functions of $x$.)

When $\tan x \ne 0$ and $\tan^2 x \ne 1$ we have $$\bullet \quad  \tan x-\cot x=(\tan^2 x-1)/\tan  x=(-\tan 2x)/2)^{-1}=-2\cot 2x.$$

So with $y=2x$ let $F= 4+\tan x-\cot x+2\tan y.$  Then by $\bullet$ we have $$F=4-2\cot 2x+2\tan y=4-2\cot y+2\tan y.$$ So everything in $F$ is now in functions of $y$. Now we see an opportunity to use  $\bullet$ again, with $y$ instead of $x.$ So we have $F=4-2(\tan y-\cot y)=4-4\tan 2y.$ And of course in this case, $\tan 2y=\tan \pi /4=1.$

The second half of your printed proof is unnecessarily complicated.

My own approach would have been to let $\tan x =a$ and calculate $F=4+(a-1/a)+2a/(1-a^2)=4-4(1-6a^2+a^4)/(4a-4a^3)$ and I would have recognized this, from experience and memory, as $4-4\tan 4x.$